# Parse ASP.NET pages to an object model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, parsing

I need to parse aspx, ascx, master files in an MVC project to an object model so that I can allow people to change particular parts and save the file back ~ A content management type of thing.

Is there anything in the framework to help me?

What I have tried.

1. **XDocument.Load**: Cannot load the
   directives and inline code blocks
2. **GetCompiledPageInstance**: created a
   MarshalByRefObject host and put it
   in the bin dir, created fine, but
   get errors when calling the
   function, probably something to do with MVC dependancies, it seems to be too painful
   to go this route.

I am just about to start on a custom parser, but wondered if someone had been down the same path and could give me a few pointers...

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to generate/update/save/execute asp.net code pages during runtime?

Comment: ive been looking for the same thing - just to parse ascx files :/ please let me know if you come up with a solution

Comment: @o.k.w VS does the initial generate, IIS does the execute, I just want to parse the files into an object model, which I can then change text, move things about and save again.

Comment: @The_Butcher, if I find a solution myself, I'll be sure to post it here

Comment: @Anthony: Have you look into webparts? Or you need more than that?

Comment: @o.k.w not sure how they would work with MVC, besides it would take alot of rework as the pages already exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I have implemented a custom parser.